# Does have GridView setSelectionFromTop (int position, int y) method

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to call method `public void setSelectionFromTop (int position, int y)` which accordingly to documentation is defined in `AbsListView` since Api 1 [setSelectionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int))  
Grid View extends AbsListView  `public class GridView extends AbsListView` so this method should be there. 
But I'm getting Runtime Exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`
What is strange that this method works for `ListView` which also extends `AbsListView` `public class ListView extends AbsListView`

Who can explain me such behavior?

**ADD**

Here is my code `mGridView.setSelectionFromTop(0, scrollHeight - mParallaxViewHeight);` IDE warns me tha this method is only available in API 21

Comment: Since you mentioned NoSuchMethodException, I'm assuming you are trying to get access to this method via Java reflection.  What does your reflective call to retrieve the Method look like?

Comment: @MichaelKrause Thanks for the response. I don't use reflection I have edited question and added my code snippet

Comment: You can use `((GridView) lv).smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(index, top, 0);` if it is enough for You.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to GridView before calling setSelectionFromTop

```
((GridView) absListView).setSelectionFromTop(...)
```

Or if it is Listview:

```
((ListView) absListView).setSelectionFromTop(...)
```

Comment: `((GridView) absListView).setSelectionFromTop(...)` doesn't work in API < 21

Comment: Yes - `setSelectionFromTop` was moved from `ListView` to `AbsListView` in API 21. The documentation hasn't been updated to reflect this (other than the method now appearing under the latter).