# Padding in GridView Dynamically not via XML

Tags: android, listview, gridview, layout, padding

I want to set Padding in Gridview like as in listview in listview we have this function like

```
ListView lv;
    index = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
 v = lv.getChildAt(0);
 top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - lv.getPaddingTop());
lv.setSelectionFromTop(index,top);
```

But in gridview we dont have such kind of function.

All we have is

```
GridView gridview;
gridview.setSelection(index);
```

By this function. I am not able to save and set padding when user scrolls GridView. It sets only index not padding

I want to save padding and set it as well.

This is getView() method of my custom adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        MyStringReaderHolder holder;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);
            holder= new MyStringReaderHolder();
          // holder.gtumcaTvFirstName =(TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.candidatesArea);
          holder.gtumcaTvLastName =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
     //   holder.gtumcaTvBirthDate  =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.songTitle2);
            //holder.gtumcaIvIcon=(ImageView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.candidatesArea);
           row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(MyStringReaderHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        GtuMcaBean mrb =data.elementAt(position);
     //  holder.gtumcaTvFirstName.setText(mrb.gtumcaFirstName);
        holder.gtumcaTvLastName.setText(mrb.gtumcaLastName);
 // holder.gtumcaTvBirthDate.setText(mrb.gtumcaBirthdate);
       //holder.gtumcaIvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: @Androider.i uploaded getview() method plz check and suggest me how to set padding in it

Comment: setSelectionFromTop is a method in AbsListView and GridView extends from it, so looks like it should be available to GridView as well

Comment: @random it is not available :(

Comment: @androider.......it will set padding to permanently a fix value if i set in layout....... i want to keep changing it like i gave example of listview programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to be getting `setSelectionFromTop` for `GridView`. See this image

[image: setSelectionFromTop]

May be you should update API level or other environment setting that you're using in your post.

**EDIT**

Try using `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` instead since a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79159) exists for `setSelectionFromTop`.

Comment: When u will implement it.logcat gives an error than no such method exist.............this method is only for abslistview bro :)

Comment: And api level i am using is 23 ..minimum is 14

Comment: Ah ok, I see this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79159.

Comment: Can you try using `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` as described in one of the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744974/does-have-gridview-setselectionfromtop-int-position-int-y-method?

Comment: The method u referenced is bit complicated for me as i am new here..can u plz help me in that ?